# How to make send_mail function send bcc emails - Django REST API

Tags: django, email, django-rest-framework

I want to send notifications to everybody (except a message author) in the chat if there is a new message in the chat. I want to send one email to all, so that nobody can see the others' email addresses (bcc-blind carbon copy). How can I do so?

Here is my view:

```
class WriteMessageCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsParticipant]
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    ...
    chat = serializer.validated_data['chat']
    chat_recipients = chat.participants.exclude(id=self.request.user.id)

    for participant in chat_recipients:
        MessageRecipient.objects.create(message_id=new_message.id, recipient_id=participant.id)

    send_new_message_notification(chat.id, new_message.author, chat_recipients)
```

Here an email is sent to all recipients at once, but in cc form (everybody can see each others' email addresses).

Here is send_mail function:

```
def send_new_message_notification(chat_id, sender: User, recipients):
    link = BASE_URL + '/messaging/chat/%s/messages' % chat_id
    send_email(
        subject='You have a new message',
        message='Click the link below to view the message:', link),
        from_email='some_email@email.com',
        recipient_list=recipients
)
```

Yes, I could do like this in a view part:

```
for participant in chat_recipients:
        MessageRecipient.objects.create(message_id=new_message.id, recipient_id=participant.id)
        send_new_message_notification(chat.id, new_message.author, participant)
```

And send one by one, but it is not efficient.

So the question is: is there any method to send an email with to all recipients at once so that they are not able to see each others' email addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Django has a `send_mass_mail` function for exactly this purpose. You can check out the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#send-mass-mail).

```
# This is more efficient, because it hits the database only
# once instead of once for each new MessageRecipient
message_recipients = [MessageRecipient(message_id=new_message.id, recipient_id=participant.id) for participant in chat_recipients]
MessageRecipient.objects.bulk_create(message_recipients)

# This will send separate emails, but will only make
# one connection with the email server so it will be
# more efficient
link = BASE_URL + '/messaging/chat/%s/messages' % chat.id
emails = (('You have a new message',
           f'Click the link below to view the message: {link}', 
           'some_email@email.com',
           [recepient]
           ) for recepient in chat_recepients)
send_mass_mail(emails, fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for refactoring the MessageRecipient instance creation. I rewrote it as your version. What about email, unfortunately, it didn't fix the problem, I still can see other recipients' email addresses as well when the notification comes... I guess it means that the mail is not sent separately.

Comment: Ou, it seems to be impossible to conceal email addresses of recipients from each other using send_mass_mail, as it is said in django documentation: _As in send_mail(), recipients in the same recipient_list will all see the other addresses in the email messages’ “To:” field._

Comment: @mahiraa notice in the django docs it says "recipients in the same recipient_list". The recipients here are in separate recipient lists. This should send separate emails. So it's not bcc, but recipients shouldn't be able to see other recipients emails.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I wrote as you said: ```
    link = BASE_URL + '/messaging/chat/%s/messages' % chat_id
    emails = (('You have a new message',
               '{} {} sent you a new message. Click the link below to view the message: \n\n{}'.format(
                sender.first_name, sender.last_name, link),
               'some_email@email.com',
               recipient
               ) for recipient in recipients)
    send_mass_mail(emails, fail_silently=False)```, and here is one last error : _'User' object is not iterable_. Don't you have any idea about how to fix it?

Comment: It is most likely that the variable `recipients` you have used, refers to a single user, and not a list of recipients, did you mean to use `chat_recipients` instead? (where you have `for recipient in recipients`)

Comment: I guess I just fixed it by making 'recipient' as a list: .....'some_email@email.com', [recipient]) for recipient in recipients).... Now it works^-^ I am not sure whether it is correct writing :D If it is not right way to write, tell me please. And thank you for your help!^-^

Comment: ah yes, that is correct, `recipient_list` should be a list.

Comment: Yes, it is chat_recipients, but in parameters it is written simply as 'recipients'.